# Change of permit of stay

Tags: passports, permits

Good day, I am a Nigerian, I have an Italian 2 years permit of stay but I am currently living in Germany with my 2 children, is it possible for me to change my Italian permit of stay to Germany permit of stay and how? Because I want to stay here and moreover I have my second child here in Germany.

Comment: Hello Vivian, your question belongs on a different part of Stackexchange. Regarding travel, keep in mind that an Italian D visa does not allow permanent stay in Germany.If you overstay in Germany, that will hurt subsequent applications.